# Переход на предыдущий и следующий элементы в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Как сделать переход на предыдущий и следующий дочерние и родительские элементы в TreeView WPF? Есть TreeView, как сделать переходы по кнопке на предыдущий и следующий (Move Up и Move Down) дочерние и родительские элементы дерева и их выделение?

Answer (score 1):

У меня была аналогичная проблема, когда я реализовывал множественный выбор в дереве. Исследование показало, что это можно сделать только вручную. Простого способа я не нашел, поэтому просто делал упорядоченный массив всех элементов дерева, искал позицию в нем, и потом определял последующие и предыдущие элементы. Для вывода всех элементов дерева использовал конструкцию `tree.GetTree().OfType<TreeViewItem>().ToList()`. Здесь `GetTree` - метод расширение, описанный [здесь](http://dev-sol.blogspot.com/2012/01/frameworkelement.html).